# JavaScript find if time is greater or smaller than array element entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Very hard to describe what I'm trying to find here - especially in the title. Best to explain with the code.

```
var time = [0,4,14,25,90,110];
```

As time passes in seconds it will be either greater or smaller than each array element. What I want to do is when clicking a button it checks which element has passed and then selects that element.

So if for example the time is currently 32 then it will match the entry 25 and set the array to time[3] which is 25 seconds.

EDIT: I forgot to say that it should also update if the time reverses back. If time is reversed back to, say 12 then it should update to the second entry which is 4 seconds

Comment: post some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why does it match 25? Because it's the greatest number that is smaller than 32? And what does "set the array to time[3]" mean?

Comment: Because 32 has passed 25 but not reached the following number 90. The array was called 'time' in my example if you check above.

Comment: please add an example of the wanted update of the edit case ...

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array and exit iteration if the time is greater than the given time.

```js
function getIndex(array, value) {
    var index = -1;
    
    array.some(function (a, i) {
        if (a > value) {
            return true;
        }
        index = i;
    });
    return index;
}

var time = [0, 4, 14, 25, 90, 110];

console.log(getIndex(time, 32));
```

Comment: I forgot to say that it should also update if the time reverses back. If time is reversed back to, say 12 then it should update to the second entry which is 4 seconds

Comment: @Hasen, please add all necessary information to the question with some use cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var time = [0, 4, 14, 25, 90, 110];
var current=32;
    var index = -1;
    
    time.forEach(function (a, i) {
        if (a > current) {
            return index;
        }
        index = i;
        console.log("It will not print 4,5 or 6=>"+index)
    });
    console.log("Result:"+index);
```

Comment: I forgot to say that it should also update if the time reverses back. If time is reversed back to, say 12 then it should update to the second entry which is 4 seconds.

Comment: If time is 12, this code will print out 1 - meaning time[1] which is 4 seconds

Comment: When you write `return index;`, this returns from the inner function you've defined; it doesn't cause the loop to stop iterating, and `forEach` ignores the return value.

Comment: Actually this code works great. How can I fix the problem you mention though, David?

Comment: actually this code is misuing return without respecting the functionality of `forEach`. this method has no early exit, which has, for example `some` or `every`. also, it looks like a copy of parts of my answer.

Comment: it woks, because even it iterates all tems, it does not update `index`, because of leaving the callback before with `return`. the value of return is irrelevanr, because `forEach` does not work with any return value.

Comment: I don't know about you but I can see that indexes :4,5,6 are never print out on console, and that final result is 3. You don't have to be so conceited with conclusion that someone copied your code. We are here to help each other.

Comment: @VladoPandžić It looks like you were trying to return from the main function (not go through the loop again); actually it does keep looping, but never again reaches the `console.log`. Think `break` versus `continue`. So it works in this case, but not in the way you intended and not in the way it might appear at first glance. This is slightly bad, as it might confuse other people reading the code. However, if you change `array` to `[0, 4, 14, 25, 90, 20]`, then this distinction is important: it will print `20` even though it rejected previous array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the time array and use find()

```js
let time = [0,4,14,25,90,110];
let find = 32;

function findRight(arr, val) {
    return arr.indexOf(Array.from(arr).reverse().find(e => { 
        return val > e;
    }));
}

console.log(findRight(time, find));
```

For your edit; While I don't understand what you mean with "*time reverses back*", you'll simply have to call the function again if you need a new result.

Comment: This is pretty good but does it reverse the array? I really want the index but the index is wrong this way. Any way to do it without reversing it?

Answer (score 0):

Here you create another array for all value less than current(32) then you select the max value from the second array with Math.max

Note:- in ecma script 6 the (...) the destructive sign convert array to values directly so you can use Math.max on it.

Then check the index of this max value in your array and replace it with the current value.

```
let time=[0,4,25,90,120];
let current =32;
let time2=[];
time.foreach(function(a,I){
if(a<current)
{ 
time2[]=a;
}
});
var j=Math.max(...time2);
var index=time.indexOf(j);
if(index!= -1){
time[index]=current;
}
```